# SwiftUI: How do I make my closure return 'Content' instead of 'some View' when calling it from another initialiser?

Tags: swift, initialization, swiftui

I am currently learning SwiftUI, and I ran into a problem.

In the below code I have two initialisers. The first one works (assuming I comment out the second one long enough to test the code). The second one does not. It throws a compiler error saying "*Cannot assign value of type 'some View' to type 'Content'.*"

What am I doing wrong here? I am able to successfully call the first initialiser from outside the struct using `Infobox() { Text("Some Text") }`, which seems to me to be the exact same syntax I'm using when trying to call it from the second initialiser. No matter how much I google, I can't seem to figure this one out.

I'd very much appreciate any help you can give.

```
struct Infobox<Content>: View where Content: View {

    let content: Content

    var body: some View {
        content
    }

    init(@ViewBuilder _ content: @escaping () -> Content) {
        self.content = content()
    }

    init(withHeader headerText: String, @ViewBuilder _ content: @escaping () -> Content) {
        self.init() {
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Text(headerText)
                    .font(.headline)
                }
                content()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you mean is probably this:

```
init<T: View>(withHeader headerText: String, @ViewBuilder _ content: @escaping () -> T) 
    where Content == VStack<TupleView<(Text, T)>> {
    self.init {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Text(headerText)
                .font(.headline)
            content()
        }
    }
}
```

The view created by this initialiser will always be of the form (And yes)

```
InfoBox<VStack<TupleView<(Text, SomeOtherView)>>>
```

In other words, this init is deciding what `Content` should be. So it is only applicable to `InfoBox`es with `Content == ThatLongTypeName`, hence the constraint.

Note that the caller can specify the type of `SomeOtherView`, but that is not `Content`! `Content` is `VStack<TupleView<(Text, SomeOtherView)>>`. Therefore, an extra generic parameter is added, and the closure return type is changed.

---

IMO, it'd be much simpler if you just did this:

```
struct Infobox<Content>: View where Content: View {

    let content: () -> Content
    let headerText: String

    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            if !headerText.isEmpty {
                Text(headerText)
                    .font(.headline)
            }
            content()
        }
    }

    // note the optional parameter here
    init(withHeader headerText: String = "", @ViewBuilder _ content: @escaping () -> Content) {
        self.content = content
        self.headerText = headerText
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Your amended initialiser really did the trick. But why does my first initialiser (without the headerText) work without all of the extra stuff, while the second one requires it?

Comment: @Robin You are not saying that the `Content` should be a particular type in the first initialiser. `Content` could be any `View` in the first initialiser. However, in the second initialiser, you are implying that `Content` must be `InfoBox<VStack<TupleView<(Text, SomeOtherView)>>>`.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense!